# How can I create a site using Pnp.core

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-js

I am trying to crate a site using . This is the code:

```
using PnP.Framework;

TeamSiteCollectionCreationInformation modernteamSiteInfo = new TeamSiteCollectionCreationInformation
                    {
                        Description = siteDescription,
                        DisplayName = siteTitle,
                        Alias = siteUrl.AbsoluteUri,
                        IsPublic = true,
                        Lcid = (uint)lcid,
                    };
 var createModernSite = await clientContext.CreateSiteAsync(modernteamSiteInfo);
```

I am not really sure how to initiate the ClientContext because I think it should  use https://tenant-admin.sharepoint.com. How can I get the ClientContext object?

I tried to use the same object from the current ClientContext, but I got this error message:

> App-Only is currently not supported, unless you provide a Microsoft
> Graph Access Token.. StackTrace:    at
> PnP.Framework.Sites.SiteCollection.CreateAsync(ClientContext
> clientContext, TeamSiteCollectionCreationInformation
> siteCollectionCreationInformation, Int32 delayAfterCreation, Int32
> maxRetryCount, Int32 retryDelay, Boolean noWait, String
> graphAccessToken, AzureEnvironment azureEnvironment)    at
> Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContextExtensions.CreateSiteAsync(ClientContext
> clientContext, TeamSiteCollectionCreationInformation
> siteCollectionCreationInformation)

Answer (score 0):

You can Create Sharepoint site using pnp core sdk like this.Before that You need to authentication for your application.

```
      var context = await _pnpContextFactory.CreateAsync("Default");
      
       var teamSiteToCreate = new TeamSiteOptions("Demo", "Demo")
       {
                Description = "My site description",
                Language = Language.English,
                Owners = new string[] { "test@xyz.onmicrosoft.com" },
       };


        SiteCreationOptions siteCreationOptions = new SiteCreationOptions()
        {
            UsingApplicationPermissions = true
        };

        var create = await context.GetSiteCollectionManager().CreateSiteCollectionAsync(teamSiteToCreate, siteCreationOptions);
       
        return Ok(Create.Uri);
```